# How can I fix "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException"

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to find how many reviews a seller on bol.com, but it is saying `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`. Here is my script:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/v/daanxl/1409231/#ratings")
reviews = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span").text
reviews = reviews.replace("\)", "")
reviews.replace("\(", "")
print(reviews)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the problem is that the Xpath will return an empty elemnt so I suggest you try the Xpath or cssSelector first in the chrome console, you can use:

```
$x('XpathHere')
```

for check what an Xpath will return or

```
$$('ccsSelectorHere')
```

for check what a css selector will return.

Answer (score 0):

To get text, first you have to wait until element will be visible. For this you can use `WebDriverWait` and `visibility_of_element_located`.
Find how to use selectors, check my example below.
You can use regular expressions to search numbers in the string. In code below, if not find any number use 0.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/v/daanxl/1409231/#ratings")
reviews = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".nav-tab__item a span"))).text
reviews_count = re.search("\\d+", reviews) if re.search("\\d+", reviews).group() else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException` as the locator you have used:

```
find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span")
```

- Doesn't identifies the element containing the number of reviews i.e. `63`.
- As per the best practices while extracting any element attribute you need to wait for the *visibility of the element*

---

To extract the number of reviews of a seller on [bol.com](https://www.bol.com/nl/v/daanxl/1409231/#ratings) i.e. `63` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `text` attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.tst_reviews_filter_all>span"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'tst_reviews_filter_all')]/span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  (63)
  ```

---

If you want to strip the `(` character from the begining and `)` character from the end you can chain the the `replace()` method as follows:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `text` attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.tst_reviews_filter_all>span"))).text.replace('(', '').replace(')', ''))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'tst_reviews_filter_all')]/span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").replace("(", "").replace(")", ""))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  63
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> Here you can find a detailed discussion on [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that the element will definitely exist there and you think you are having this problem just because of slow internet;

```
from time import sleep
def safe_sleep(function):
    while True:
       sleep(0.1)
       try:
           return function()
       except NoSuchElementException:
           continue
```

this function will do the job easily, it works for me.

usage;

```
safe_sleep(lambda: browser.find_element_by_id("foo")).send_keys("bar")
```

**Note: If the element is not really there, the program will run forever. So don't use this method unless you're sure it exists.**

Answer (score -1):

Either your xpath is wrong or some of that element cannot may not present by that xpath.

You may use a **try catch block** to prevent program from stopping.

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/v/daanxl/1409231/#ratings")
try:
    reviews = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span").text
catch NoSuchElementException:
    print("Element not found")
reviews = reviews.replace("\)", "")
reviews.replace("\(", "")
print(reviews)
```

Comment: Try / catch will prevent the program from stopping, but will likely break the code at a later point due to a previous step failing in the try catch block. This approach should only be used for flaky web elements with some kind of retry implementation in place.

Answer (score -1):

To get the no of reviews Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following xpath.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/v/daanxl/1409231/#ratings")
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='nav-tab__link tst_reviews_filter_all js_all_link'][contains(.,'Alles')]/span"))).text.replace('(','').replace(')',''))
```

**Output on console:**

```
63
```